# Moq with delegate in Returns always returns null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, delegates, moq

I am trying to make a Mock object for a class, so that the Mock object has access to all of the same methods as the original class, except for the one method I want to perform differently. However, my Mock object has *no* methods when I view it in Debug mode, and all of the calls I *don't* want to alter (for testing purposes) return null. Here is the way I am presently doing this:

```
var originalClass = ContainingClass.OtherContainingClass.ClassIWantToMock;
var originalClassMock = new Mock<IClassToMock> {CallBase = true};

originalClassMock.Setup(c => c.MethodToMock(It.IsAny<paramType>()))
    .Returns<TReturn>(originalClass.MethodToMock);
```

I get the same result whether I *only* mock the method I want to change, as well as when I mock every method in the class. I suspect this is because IClassToMock is an interface, even though I am feeding in methods from an object that implements that interface. This is probably why CallBase does not make a difference--I get the same result regardless of whether CallBase is set. Is there a way to mock an interface by setting up methods that run delegates from a class implementing that interface?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to run a delegate of an interface within a test? I'd recommend that your return simply returns an object or a value which the system under test can manipulate for your test and not depend on how that interface is implemented.

Comment: Problem is, the code this class needs to produce is not used by the test itself, it's used by the IAsyncJob I'm trying to test--I need a class that implements the interface, functions the same as the normal class that implements that interface, and only has one method act differently. After staring at this for too long, though, I'm probably just going to make a new class that implements the interface but has a public Func for each method. Thanks!

Comment: I'm unsure what it is that you are testing here, but you shouldn't be running code from dependencies of your System Under Test as part of your test. If I have a interface `ICalculate.Add(...)`, I wouldn't want to run this when using the `ICalculate` interface, I'd much rather know that I was calling it correctly and using it's result wisely, but again I'm unsure what your exact use case is.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense when you put it like that. I'm not convinced that our team is running unit tests properly, but I haven't come to understand the theory of unit tests as well as I'd like. Thank you though.

Comment: In the "original" class `ContainingClass.OtherContainingClass.ClassIWantToMock`, is that special method `MethodToMock` which you want to treat differently, marked `virtual` or marked `override` without `sealed`? Is the original class public and non-sealed with all containing classes being public as well? And does the original class possess a suitable and accessible non-static constructor (possibly simply the default constructor)? If all that is true, maybe you want `new Mock<ContainingClass.OtherContainingClass.ClassIWantToMock>`.

Comment: There is a typo in your example, it should be `originalClassMock.Setup(c => c.MethodToMock(It.IsAny<paramType>())).Returns<paramType>(originalClass.MethodToMock);`. Other than that, this should work. Try using a strict mock if you do not understand what is going on. The type arguments to `Returns<...>` are the types of the inbound parameters of `MethodToMock`.